# Обновить дату в mysql через php

Tags: mysql, php, sql

В базе есть таблица

```
<sql>
-- Структура таблицы `date_dafault`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `date_dafault` (
  `id` INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_default` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `date_dafault`
--

INSERT INTO `date_dafault` (`id`, `date_default`) VALUES
(1, '2012-08-14');
</sql>
<br><br>
```

Как мне через `php` обновить дату на текущую?

Answer (score 4):

Выполнить запрос

```
"UPDATE `date_dafault` set date_default=NOW() WHERE id=1"
```

Comment: отхватил плюсиков за халявный ответ )

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = 1;
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$request = "UPDATE date_dafault SET date_default = $today WHERE id = $id;";
mysql_query($request);
```

Comment: запрос не валидный у тебя

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `date_dafault` set date_default=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id=1
```